How to achieve consistent background-image: cover effect with sliced background images?
I'm trying to display an image within a 100px x 100px container. The image's aspect ratio is not 1:1, so using background-image: cover on the container fills it without distortion.
To achieve a special effect, I divided the image into five 20px wide slices and displayed them in separate divs arranged with flex. Each div uses background-image to show a specific part of the image, with background-position adjusted accordingly.
However, when I set each slice's background-size to cover, the result does not match the effect of simply using background-image: cover on the container. I'm wondering if there's a way to make each slice work like background-image: cover, so the image displays the same way it does when using background-image: cover on the entire container.
Is there a way to make each slice use background-size: cover and achieve the same effect as using background-image: cover on the entire container?


* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slice-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.slices {
  height: 100px;
  width: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602431039221-64c1be92ad52?w=500&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjB8fGZha2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D");
  /* Ideally, I want to use background-size: cover here but it does not match the effect */
  /* background-size: cover; */
}

.slices-1 {
  background-position: 0px;
}

.slices-2 {
  background-position: -20px;
}

.slices-3 {
  background-position: -40px;
}

.slices-4 {
  background-position: -60px;
}

.slices-5 {
  background-position: -80px;
}

.cover-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602431039221-64c1be92ad52?w=500&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjB8fGZha2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D");
}
<!-- Displaying image slices -->
<div class="slice-container">
  <div class="slices slices-1"></div>
  <div class="slices slices-2"></div>
  <div class="slices slices-3"></div>
  <div class="slices slices-4"></div>
  <div class="slices slices-5"></div>
</div>

<br />

<!-- Full container background -->
<div class="cover-container"></div>




what you want is not logical. Using cover with two elements having different sizes will result in a background-image with different sizes as well. If you are using the same image, you cannot use "cover"

You can use cover if you put the background on a pseudo before element rather than on the slice itself.
That way you can position the pseudo element, having given it 100px width and height and it will be positioned correctly in its 'host' slice.
The slices have to have overflow: hidden.
This way you don't need to know anything about the size or aspect ratio of the background image, CSS does the positioning and sizing for you. No JS involved.
This snippet has given the flex a gap so you can see the individual slices more clearly.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Image Slices Issue</title>
</head>
<style>
  * {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .slice-container {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
  }
  
  .slices {
    height: 100px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .slices::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602431039221-64c1be92ad52?w=500&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjB8fGZha2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D");
    /* Ideally, I want to use background-size: cover here but it does not match the effect */
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
  .slices-1::before {
    left: 0px;
  }
  
  .slices-2::before {
    left: -20px;
  }
  
  .slices-3::before {
    left: -40px;
  }
  
  .slices-4::before {
    left: -60px;
  }
  
  .slices-5::before {
    left: -80px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <!-- Displaying image slices -->
  <div class="slice-container">
    <div class="slices slices-1"></div>
    <div class="slices slices-2"></div>
    <div class="slices slices-3"></div>
    <div class="slices slices-4"></div>
    <div class="slices slices-5"></div>
  </div>


</html>




Wow, you’re amazing! But I’d like to understand the principle behind this—how does using left make each slice display correctly? I just tried changing it to background-position, but the effect no longer looks like a covered image; I had to use left as you suggested.

We are using left on the pseudo element, not on the slice itself. But we also want to use background-size cover - so that CSS does the work for us regardless of the relative dimensions of the background image and the 100px by 100px. So, first the background image fills the pseudo element, and all the pseudo elements look the same therefore. Then we want to position each one relative to its actual slice. I did that with the left (but could be translateX). And we show only the part that is within the slice by including overflow: hidden.

You're very much appreciated, thank you!

You can imitate what cover does using background-size: x y with proper values. cover basically Scales the image (while preserving its ratio) to the smallest possible size to fill the container (that is: both its height and width completely cover the container).
You can use JavaScript to calculate the correct x and y but let's assume the image size is indeed 500 by 750. This means for a container of 100 by 100 we would need the image to be 100 by 150.
This will work well for images where the height is greater than the width. But background-position-x would be trickier to calculate, yet possible, for images where the width is greater than height.


.slice-container,
.cover-container,
.fake-cover-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.fake-cover-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 150px;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602431039221-64c1be92ad52?w=500&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjB8fGZha2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D");
}

.slices {
  background-size: 100px 150px;
  background-position;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Image Slices Issue</title>
</head>
<style>
  * {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .slice-container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .slices {
    height: 100px;
    width: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602431039221-64c1be92ad52?w=500&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjB8fGZha2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D");
    /* Ideally, I want to use background-size: cover here but it does not match the effect */
    /* background-size: cover; */
  }
  
  .slices-1 {
    background-position-x: 0px;
  }
  
  .slices-2 {
    background-position-x: -20px;
  }
  
  .slices-3 {
    background-position-x: -40px;
  }
  
  .slices-4 {
    background-position-x: -60px;
  }
  
  .slices-5 {
    background-position-x: -80px;
  }
  
  .cover-container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602431039221-64c1be92ad52?w=500&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjB8fGZha2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D");
  }
</style>

<body>


  <div style="display: flex; gap: 10px;">
    <!-- Displaying image slices -->
    Slices:
    <div class="slice-container">
      <div class="slices slices-1"></div>
      <div class="slices slices-2"></div>
      <div class="slices slices-3"></div>
      <div class="slices slices-4"></div>
      <div class="slices slices-5"></div>
    </div>


    Cover:
    <!-- Full container background -->
    <div class="cover-container"></div>


    Faked<br>Cover:
    <!-- Full container background -->
    <div class="fake-cover-container"></div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>




Thank you, I mostly understand. However, I’d like to know why an image with a width greater than its height requires tracking position-x? Since each of my slices is set to a width of 20px, shouldn’t they all track 20px sequentially?

If width > height than height must be 100px than width > 100px, so each slice should be bigger than 20px. I think 20 / y * x
